# Find the First Shortest Path and then the Second Shortest Path in a Matrix

Tags: matlab, dijkstra

So as the title says I want my code to output the full shortest paths, my matrix has 10 nodes so the output should be for example 1-2-6-10 but in my case, the output for both the first shortest path and the second only gives the value of 10 the last vertex and I want it to show the full path from node 1 to node 10, the last one. This matrix is just an example because I want Matlab to read a matrix from excel.

```
matrix = [0  3  6  8  2  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf;          3  0  5  7  9   1  inf  inf  inf  inf;          6  5  0  5  8   10  2  inf  inf  inf;          8  7  5  0  4   9   14  3  inf  inf;          2  9  8  4  0   5   12  15  4  inf;          inf  1  10  9  5  0   10  20  25  5;          inf  inf  2  14  12  10  0   12  30  35;          inf  inf  inf  3  15  20  12  0   25  40;          inf  inf  inf  inf  4  25  30  25  0   45;          inf  inf  inf  inf  inf  5  35  40  45  0];


% Input:
start = 1;
ending = 10;

% Initialize variables
n = size(matrix,1); % number of vertices
d = inf(1,n); % distance array
d(start) = 0; % starting vertex distance = 0
prev = zeros(1,n); % predecessor array
S = false(1, n); % set of labeled vertices
S(start) = true;

for i = 1:size(matrix,1)
    for j = 1:size(matrix,2)
        if matrix(i,j) == 0
            matrix(i,j) = inf;
        end
    end
end

% First shortest path
matrix = matrix + matrix';
matrix(matrix == inf) = 0;
matrix(matrix > 0) = inf;

while S(ending) == false;
    % Select vertex with smallest distance
    [,v] = min(d(~S));
    v = find(~S,1,'first');
    S(v) = true; % "permanently" label vertex

    % Update distances and predecessors of neighbors
    for u = find(matrix(v,:)~=inf)
        if d(v) + matrix(v,u) < d(u) && matrix(v,u) <= inf

            d(u) = d(v) + matrix(v,u);
            prev(u) = v;
        end
    end
end

% Output first shortest path
path = [ending];
while prev(path(end)) ~= 0
    path = [path, prev(path(end))];
end
fprintf('First Shortest Path: ')
for i = 1:length(path)
    fprintf('%d ', path(i))
end

fprintf('\n')



% Second shortest path
for i = 2:length(path)
    matrix(path(i), path(i-1)) = inf; % remove the edge from first path
end

d = inf(1,n); % distance array
d(start) = 0; % starting vertex distance = 0
prev = zeros(1,n); % predecessor array
S = false(1, n); % set of labeled vertices
S(start) = true;

% Repeat the process to find the second shortest path
while S(ending) == false
    % Select vertex with smallest distance
    [,v] = min(d(~S)); 
    v = find(~S,1,'first');
    S(v) = true; % "permanently" label vertex
    % Update distances and predecessors of neighbors
    for u = find(matrix(v,:)~=inf)
        if d(v) + matrix(v,u) < d(u) && matrix(v,u) <= inf

            d(u) = d(v) + matrix(v,u);
            prev(u) = v;
        end
    end
end

% Output second shortest path
path = [ending];
while prev(path(1)) ~= 0
    path = [prev(path(1)),path];
end
fprintf('Second Shortest Path: ')
for i = 1:length(path)
    fprintf('%d ', path(i))
end
fprintf('\n') `
```

I tried using a different Matrix at first, but still the same.
I want the First Shortest path from node 1 to node 10 and then remove that path and give me the second shortest path.

Comment: Your title suggests something about the second shortest path, and you show code for that, but that part of the code seems irrelevant to the problem you’re facing. I suggest you shorten your code and change your title so we can focus to the one problem at hand, see [mre].

Comment: In  that same vein, remove the Excel part, just hard-code a small example matrix in your code, so that we can copy-paste the code and run it exactly like you’re running it.

Comment: The problem seems to be inside the while loop

Comment: Please [edit] your post.

Comment: shortest path, but where from where to? 1st row down? left to right? sum 50 with least elements one per row? per column? please define distance

Comment: I'm going to be honest, very little of this code makes any sense. For example, have a look at `matrix` just before the first `while` loop. All of the nonzero values are replaced with `inf` and all of the `inf` values are replaced with zero. Is this what you were expecting? If so, then your desired path of 1-2-6-10 will never be found because all of the distances between those vertices are infinite. (I'm assuming that `matrix` is meant to be an adjacency matrix.)

Comment: I suggest you step through your code line by line, either with the debugger or manually, and verify that each line does what you expect.

Comment: I have tried to check what is wrong and it seems to be here

% Update distances and predecessors of neighbors
    for u = find(matrix(v,:)~=inf)
        if d(v) + matrix(v,u) < d(u) && matrix(v,u) <= inf

            d(u) = d(v) + matrix(v,u);
            prev(u) = v;
        end
    end

the if conditions are not met.

Comment: `matrix(v,u)` is ***always*** `inf`, so regardless of what `d(u)` is, `matrix(v,u)` is never less than `d(u)`. On the other hand, since nothing is greater than `inf`, `matrix(v,u) <= inf` is always true, so it serves no purpose. Please edit your question when you have updates or clarifications to make.

Comment: I need a fix for the code, I want to output the full path, not just the last vertex, if I knew how to fix the code I would not have put a question here

Comment: @CarlosRamos Stack Overflow is intended for specific, focused programming questions, not "debug my code and fix all the things wrong with it". As I stated earlier, you need to step through your code line by line and verify that each line is doing what you think it should. If you have a *specific* question after you've done that, we'll be glad to try to help you.